# how to download form in my webpage as pdf in php

Tags: php, pdf, html

i have a form to be submitted in my web page.i need my form to be downloaded as pdf when user click download as PDF button at the bottom of the page after submitting the form.i tried with several examples. pdf is downloading but it is downloading asp hp script.can anyone help and i pdf should contain only form but not header and footer of my webpage ...

Answer (score 1):

Pdfcrowd offers a very simple and straightforward way to save your web  pages to PDF

Just paste the following code verbatim into your HTML.

```
<a href="//pdfcrowd.com/url_to_pdf/">Save to PDF</a>
```

Comment: clicking on save to pdf link directing to a page  (webpage not found)

Answer (score 0):

**FPDF** is an awesome pdf generator library. Its very easy to use and well documented. You can try it form [FPDF Site](http://www.fpdf.org/)

Comment: is this print my current webpage or i need to give the my html to this.is this is dynamic to my webpage?

Comment: do you want to convert html website to PDF? If yes then you can use DOMpdf. I think it will helpful
https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

Comment: actually what i need is i dont to want to use any third party library .only i need to download the form in my page as pdf after clicking submit button

Comment: thats why you should to use third party library to download your form as pdf otherwise you have to use your own methods :)